# PHP - issue in adding 30 min to time

Tags: php, datetime, while-loop

I am facing a weird issue, what I am trying to do here is to add 30 minutes to a specified time for multiple iterations using a while loop. Below is the code I am trying and not sure where it has gone wrong.

**My Code**

```
function session_slot_compare(){
$min_count = 3;
$time_now  = '1:30';
$time_now_new = date('H:i', strtotime($time_now));
 $duration_bits[0] = $time_now_new;
$i=0;
while($i<$min_count){
    $time_now_new = date("H:i", strtotime('+30 minutes', $time_now_new));
    $duration_bits[$i] = $time_now_new;
    $i++;
}
print_r($duration_bits);}
```

**Expected Output**

I am actually expecting the output to be like `Array ( [0] => 01:30 [1] => 02:00 [2] => 02:30 )`

**Actual Output**

But I am getting the output as `Array ( [0] => 01:30 [1] => 00:30 [2] => 00:30 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in the `strtotime('+30 minutes', $time_now_new)` you pass not a valid 2-nd argument. It should be a timestamp, but in your case it's a string. The shortest way to fix the problem is to add one more `strtotime()` call, like the following:

```
$time_now_new = date("H:i", strtotime('+30 minutes', strtotime($time_now_new)));
```

It'll work exactly in the way you expect.